# Fluid Grid Layout Control

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, fluid-layout

sorry for asking as I hate asking questions but sometimes its the last resort.

I am pulling my hair out over here and I have read hundreds of pages over the weekend and just can't get my head around how to do achieve this.

I want to have a simple 4 column 'home' landing page for desktop and ipad (sub pages will revert to 2 columns - content and sidebar). When the user goes on to a iPhone I want the user to see 2 columns.

I have managed to either get the iphone to display a scaled down version of the 4 columns using the grid system or I have managed to get it displaying 1 column, neither of which help me.

I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve if it helps but I would really appreciate if someone who has had some experience in this field to point me in the right direction as I just cant figure it out.

I am developing using wordpress and have tried bootstrap, responsive theme and bones and getting the same results with each. Each using a responsive fluid grid. I may be barking up the wrong tree but if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

[image: example of what I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS media queries, based on screen size / device width.

This will allow your CSS to style the widths of columns on each device...

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html

Comment: You may also find the following viewport meta useful when deailing with fluid widths accross deifferent devices:Viewport basics
       `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Hey thank you, you seem to have put me on the right track which is a load better than I was looking yesterday. I have now managed to get the iPhone browser to show the website in the correct number of columns. The issue I have now is that each block is 220px wide so there is a load of space on the iPhones 640px width screen 220 x 2 plus 10px margin = 450px wide. This leaves 190px spare so it doesn't look like the iPhone screen above - any suggestions? Thanks again by the way...

Comment: With a bit of playing around I have managed to get the site to do what I want by using %'s so happy days. Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem, whenever I work with responsive / fluid layouts - I tend to go with percentages all the way. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Adobe Dreamweaver now also support what are called "Fluid Grid Layouts" which are worth a look for this kind of issue. They are also very helpful for quickly solving inter-device layout issues. You can design easily for Mobile, Tablet, and Desktop in one interface!